# How to display open file descriptors but not using lsof command

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Hi I have read [Here](http://www.netadmintools.com/art295.html) that lsof is not an accurate way of getting the number of File Descriptors that are currently open. He recommended to use this command instead

```
 cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
```

While this command displays the number of FD's, how do you display the list of open file descriptors that the command above just counted?

Comment: You probably want to know if your ulimit is exceeded, right? I blogged about this under http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Is_my_ulimit_exceeded; most importantly, the ulimit is a per-process restriction that you can find under /proc/PID/limits and instead of lsof I would use ls /proc/PID/fd to list the process' file descriptors.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There are two reasons `lsof | wc -l` doesn't count file descriptors. One is that it lists things that aren't open files, such as loaded dynamically linked libraries and current working directories; you need to filter them out. Another is that `lsof` takes some time to run, so can miss files that are opened or closed while it's running; therefore the number of listed open files is approximate. Looking at `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr` gives you an exact value at a particular point in time.

`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr` is only useful when you need the exact figure, mainly to check for resource exhaustion. If you want to list the open files, you need to call `lsof`, or use some equivalent method such as trawling `/proc/*/fd` manually.

Comment: Hi thanks for giving a good explanation Gilles. I tried ls /proc/*/fd and got all the open fd's at that time. Its producing an output with some color coding, I'll just have to look at the manual.

Comment: @dimas `/proc/*/fd` directories contain symbolic links to the open files. For visual inspection, use `ls -l`. For automated treatment, use `readlink` to extract the link target.

Comment: Just use ls -l but i'll experiment with readlink. I tried other /proc/PID/maps and other options as specified here http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html. Thanks again for the additional info.

Comment: Note that file-nr outputs the amount of allocated filedescriptors, not the actual amount of used and opened ones.

Comment: /proc/sys/fs/file-nr gives me 3872 (and two other numbers). How can this be the count of files I have open if ulimit -n shows me 1024?

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk `file-nr` is the total number of open files across the system. `ulimit -n` sets the maximum number of files open by each process.

Comment: @Gilles, do you have any reference for your statement? I looked into the man page and it explicitely states for -v that it is a per-process limitation but does NOT state this for -n.

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk All settings of `setrlimit` (the system call underlying the `ulimit` shell command) are per-process. They affect only the process that makes the call (and indirectly the processes that it later forks).

Comment: you are right, I verified this with a test program, pasted to http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Ulimit

Answer (score 29):

Process information is kept dynamically by the system in directories under /proc.  For example the process with PID 1234 will have a directory called /proc/1234.

There are quite a bit of information in there but right now you are interested in the /proc/1234/**fd** subdirectory.

NOTE:  You need to have root permissions to view or open files for processes that you do not own, as well as for SetUID processes.

Example:

```
root@johan-HP-ProBook-6560b-LG654EA-ACQ:/proc# ls -l 2443/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 0 -> pipe:[13637]
l-wx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 1 -> /home/johan/.xsession-errors
lrwx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 10 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 11 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 12 -> socket:[39495]
lrwx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 13 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lr-x------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 14 -> anon_inode:inotify
lrwx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 15 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
l-wx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 16 -> pipe:[37885]
lr-x------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 17 -> pipe:[37886]
l-wx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 2 -> /home/johan/.xsession-errors
l-wx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 21 -> pipe:[167984]
lr-x------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 22 -> pipe:[167985]
l-wx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 23 -> pipe:[170009]
lr-x------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 24 -> pipe:[170010]
lrwx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 3 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lr-x------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 4 -> pipe:[14726]
lrwx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 5 -> socket:[14721]
l-wx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 6 -> pipe:[14726]
lrwx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 7 -> socket:[14730]
lrwx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 8 -> socket:[13984]
lrwx------ 1 johan johan 64 Feb 27 10:26 9 -> socket:[14767]

root@johan-HP:/proc# cat 2443/fdinfo/2
pos:    1244446
flags:  0102001
```

Also have a look at the rest of the files under /proc ... a lot of useful information from the system resides here.