# File descriptor counts differ

Tags: linux, proc, file-descriptors

There is something fundamental that I miss here, I am sure.

On a system I run:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
2240    0   763924
```

On the same system, if I do :

```
sum=0; for pid in /proc/[0-9]*; do fd=$(ls $pid/fd | wc -l); sum=$((sum + fd)); done; echo $sum
```

The result is far less: `872`. How come? Can someone please explain? Thank you.

Comment: See [Why file-nr and lsof count on open files differs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176967/100397) here, and [Number of file descriptors: different between /proc/sys/fs/file-nr and /proc/$pid/fd](https://serverfault.com/q/485262/267016) on [SF]