# how to know if we reached the max value of fs.file-max

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, lsof, open-files

On our Linux RHEL servers `fs.file-max` is set to `100000`

```
sysctl -p | grep fs.file-max
fs.file-max = 100000
```

From my understanding the `file-max` kernel parameter refers to open file descriptors, and `file-nr` gives us the current number of open file descriptors. But `lsof` lists all open files, including files which are not using file descriptors – such as current working directories, memory mapped library files, and executable text files.

Is the following `lsof` really a good indication that we have reached the `fs.file-max` value?

```
lsof | wc -l
```

or

```
[[ `lsof | wc -l` -gt 100000 ]] && echo "please increase the fs.file-max"
```

other relevant links - [How to display open file descriptors but not using lsof command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66235/how-to-display-open-file-descriptors-but-not-using-lsof-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
[[ `lsof | wc -l` -gt 100000 ]] && echo "please increase the fs.file-max"
```

will be misleading. See reference below.

Based on [RHEL 5 Tuning](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/tuning_and_optimizing_red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_oracle_9i_and_10g_databases/chap-oracle_9i_and_10g_tuning_guide-setting_file_handles), the output of `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr` can be used. We can compare the **first** and **last** fields of the output. The first field shows *total allocated file handles* and the last field shows *the maximum file handles that can be allocated*. So setup a check so that once, say 90% is reached, a warning is displayed:

```
[[ $(echo "$(cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr | cut -f1) / $(cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr | cut -f3) * 100" | bc -l) -ge 90 ]] \
  && echo "90% reached. Please increase the fs.file-max"
```

---

Some difference between `lsof` and `file-nr` output:

*The file-max kernel parameter refers to open file descriptors, and file-nr gives us the current number of open file descriptors. But lsof lists all open files, including files which are not using file descriptors – such as current working directories, memory mapped library files, and executable text files.*

See [Reference](https://www.netadmintools.com/art295.html)

Comment: so in that case - what actually the command - lsof | wc -l say?  , what value from this command is indicate ?

Comment: Updated my answer.